# What is the meaning of "you will lose the juice"

Tags: meaning

The text is

> In fact, in this state how will you treat this person you’re in a relationship with?
>   You’ll probably treat them in a way that will make them not want to be in a relationship
>   with you.  If not, leaving the relationship permanently, in the moment they are not going
>   to want to relate to you, so **you will lose the juice**.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Hello! Where did you read this? Can you please post the link, thanks.

Comment: What do you think?  Did you look up the meanings of "lose" and "juice"?  What meanings do you think might apply?

Comment: @stangdon - I agree with you, we want people to [show their research](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) when they post a question. That said, I can see why this particular question might vex a learner.

Comment: there isnt any link. i read it from an essay.invitation to responsibility

Comment: @J.R. - Oh, I actually agree with you, but if you google "define juice", you get some answers that are at least suggestive.  I just want to be sure that the OP has done that and still doesn't understand, rather than just using ELL as a substitute for a dictionary or web search.

Comment: could it  mean respect or power .google gave th at meaning as a slang.i dont know could it be correct

Comment: user42804 - What stangdon and I are both trying to say is that, when asking about what something means, it's generally considered poor practice to simply ask, "What does this mean?" It's far better to say, "When I looked up this word on sites A and B, I learned X, Y, and Z, but I'm still confused." [Read this meta post for more guidance and information](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/). @stangdon - I understood where you were going with your comment, but a brand-new user might have trouble catching the gist of it (hence my follow-on remark).

Comment: What is the essay called, (invitation to responsibility?) and who is the author? Is it a school essay by any chance? Is it your homework? I can *guess* the meaning, "juice" probably stands for momentum, energy, spark... But this sounds American English to me, and I'm not American. So, I'm outta here.

Comment: it is a text of my professor speech at one of his conferences.and i have to translate to my native language .its my home work.yes its name is invitation to responsibility

Comment: It seems incredibly unlikely that any native Anglophone accorded the status of "professor" could write such poor English. The last sentence is syntactic garbage, and the sudden introduction of such a slangy usage as ***juice*** in the context of relatively "high register" text just comes across as ignorant in the extreme.

Answer (score 2):

The author is referring to the *energy*, *vigor*, or *vitality* of a relationship as its

> juice

by ending a relationship, the relationship will "lose its juice".

"Juice" is also AmE slang for [electricity](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/juice%20[electricity]), a form of energy.

In the 1970's, because of his running ability at [USC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e25kfgmKV48&t=0m30s) and [Buffalo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1cu5ykSda0&t=0m49s), OJ Simpson was called
"The Juice" as a play on words, OJ (orange juice), and a nod to his prowess.

> [The Juice is loose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2kx3MGfAkU&t=0m14s)